# Block validation failed when adjusting default block height attribute

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to adjust the default height attribute of a spacer block. The default height is added correctly, but I get the following errors in console:

```
Block validation: Block validation failed for `core/spacer` ({name: 'core/spacer', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

> <div style="height:24px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

> <div style="height:200px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
```

I enqueued the script in the enqueue_block_editor_assets hook.

```
   function enqueue_gutenberg_scripts() {
        $theme = wp_get_theme();
        $version = $theme->get('Version');
        wp_enqueue_script('edit-gutenberg-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gutenberg.js', ['wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor'], $version, true);
    }
    add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_gutenberg_scripts');
```

Then I registered the following filter:

```
wp.hooks.addFilter(
  "blocks.registerBlockType",
  "my-script/extend-block-attributes",
  (settings, name) => {
    if (name == "core/spacer") {
      return {
        ...settings,
        attributes: {
          ...settings.attributes,
          height: {
            type: "string",
            default: "24px",
          },
        },
      };
    }
    return settings;
  }
);
```